# Magento - Risks to use Google checkout as option on Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento, radio-button, android-pay, google-checkout

Recently I played with Google Checkout a.k.a Google Wallet.
My task was to make it work as option in payment methods step
of Onepage Checkout.

My version of Mangento is CE 1.6.2.0

By default we have Google Checkout form only on the cart page,
but not on Onepage Checkout page. I looked at the admin settings 
of the module  ( Google Api ), but didn't find an option to enable it for the 
checkout page.

I found, that we have form template in googlecheckout/form.phtml
and it seems, that it was planned to work on the checkout page.

I decided to "shoot" and created simple extension, that rewrites
Mage_GoogleCheckout_Model_Payment so I changed

```
protected $_canUseCheckout = false; to protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
```

and voila, the option appeared on the checkout page as payment method.

I did some test orders in sandbox mode and everything seems to be fine,
the products and the shipping amounts are correct. Also the billing
information was automatically populated in Google Wallet page and
it wasn't needed to populate again the same information of the checkout page
again in Google Wallet.

What bothers me is the fact, that by default this "feature" wasn't available
and may be there is a reason, why the folks of the Magento core made it
work in that way.

Basically my question is do you see any risk to use Google Checkout as option in checkout page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not allowed according to google policies.

http://checkout.google.com/seller/policies.html

'Do not position or present Google Checkout as a form of payment equivalent to Visa, MasterCard, etc.
Google Checkout aggregates existing payment types to allow buyers and merchants to transact. Google Checkout is not a form of payment that replaces or is equivalent to existing payment types and must not be presented as such. Buyers using the e-commerce provider's standard checkout flow should not, therefore, encounter a payment field drop-down with Google Checkout listed alongside payment types like Visa, MasterCard, American Express, etc. Instead, the buyer should have the option of selecting Google Checkout as a distinct checkout flow as required in 4b.'

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! As developer I am focused on the technical details of the work and usually I am not familiar with the policies and etc. Hope, that will be helpful for the rest part of the community. Thanks.